# How do I run a selenium web driver script 24/7

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, instagram

How would I run a selenium web driver script 24/7 on the cloud? I'm looking to run an instagram bot 24/7 without having to constantly open chrome and have pycharm open all the time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/benaiah/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://instagram.com")
    sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
    .send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\
    .send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')\
    .click()

sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")\
    .click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")\
    .click()
sleep(3)

for k in range(4):
    for i in range(5):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')\
            .click()
        sleep(1)
    driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so here would be my two suggestions.

1. Run your webdriver in headless mode.  Keeps it from using an open window, and lessens the resource draw.
2. Don't use pycharm for execution, just run the script from your command prompt.

If you run it "on the cloud" you'll have to get space on an online platform but most are not free.  And some also have Terms of Service that this bot would violate.